# Access the methods of primitive Rust types

Tags: methods, rust, primitive-types

How can I access the methods of primitive types in Rust?

Concretely, I want to pass either one of the two slice methods `split_first_mut` and `split_last_mut` to a function operating on slices. I know you can wrap them in closures as a workaround, but I’d like to know if direct access is possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the methods on primitives just like regular types:

```
u8::to_le();
str::from_utf8();
<[_]>::split_first_mut();
```

You can create a function that accepts a slice ops function:

```rust
fn do_thing<T>(f: impl Fn(&mut [u8])) -> Option<(&mut T, &mut [T])>) {
    // ...
}
```

And pass in both `split_first_mut` and `split_last_mut`:

```rust
fn main() {
    do_thing(<[_]>::split_first_mut);
    do_thing(<[_]>::split_last_mut);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to refer to the method using fully-qualified syntax. In a nutshell: `<T>::{method_name}` where `T` is the type and `{method_name}` is the name of the method. For example, if you're modifying a `[i32]` then you'd to prefix the method name with `<[i32]>::` like this:

```rust
fn apply_fn<T, U>(t: T, t_fn: fn(T) -> U) -> U {
    t_fn(t)
}

fn main() {
    let mut items: Vec<i32> = vec![1, 2, 3];

    let slice: &mut [i32] = items.as_mut_slice();
    let first_split = apply_fn(slice, <[i32]>::split_first_mut);

    let slice: &mut [i32] = items.as_mut_slice();
    let last_split = apply_fn(slice, <[i32]>::split_last_mut);
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=5a0b1f7923d9631e72a77df8fd2b7e45)